# Permalinks not working (404) for the 'item' post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, 404-error

I have searched various forums and blogs, however I could not find the isuse so far, neither a way to fix it.

`item` does not seem to be a wordpress-reserved word.

My custom post type registers just fine. I can work with it from admin, edit, delete, preview, assign terms, publish... .

However any time I try to visit the permalink (e.g. `http://www.example.com/item/test-item-77/`) it goes to the 404 page!

Had someone tried this out with the latest version of WP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your permalinks in the backend under Settings -> Permalinks. Be sure to "Save Changes" even if you don't make any changes. It seems to refresh the permalinks.

Also verify the "slug" is set properly when you're setting up your post type.

Comment: tried this, not working

Comment: Could you post the code you're using for register_post_type()?

Comment: I found the problem, there was this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kih-web-directory-wordpress-plugin/ . Once I deactivate it the permalinks are working.